# Is it possible to install Android KitKat or newers versions to Samsung Galaxy Beam i8530?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung, rom-update

I couldn't find any answer on how to install any android version higher than JellyBean on Galaxy Beam, do I need to buy a new phone?

Comment: No. I searched XDA and your phone has no own category and the only ROMs are based on 2.3.6. Time to get a new phone, 4 years are kind of old in our fast evolving technology.

Comment: @GiantTree True, but other Samsung devices, like the Tab 2, do have Lollipop and marshmallow ROMs for them. I hear that a n beta for the tab 2 will be in development once cyanogenMod start releasing builds of it.

Comment: @DanB each and every device is different (mostly). So each device needs people that compile and maintain CM and also have to first create a running kernel. Nobody has done that for the Galaxy Beam so there is no KitKat for that device.

Comment: @GiantTree Aw, snap. OK.

Answer (score 0):

The phone uses a NovaThor U8500 SoC, the manufacturer of which, ST-Ericsson was [dissolved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ST-Ericsson) in 2013, not long after its release, thus cutting support for it. Although there are devices with the same SoC having higher Android version and third-party ROMs (namely Galaxy S Advanced and Xperia P/U/Sola), your device appeals to a much more niche market and therefore doesn't enjoy a large enough user base for developers to come and develop for it.

So the definitive answer is, **yes, go for something new**. And no gimmicks like those projectors - more gimmicks means less possibility for the community to support it.